# Selenium webdriver crashes when the test takes longer than 10 mins

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a screening application which has more than 20 sections. So far tests that are shorter than 5-10 minutes are working fine. But I have one test that is supposed to go through the whole application under ideal conditions and that test takes longer to ex seems to fail at the same point every time. I get the error

```
Test 'ScreeningTests.ScreeningPageTest("firefox").CompleteScreeningTest()' failed: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/c8495f3b-b8ec-4f19-80d3-b1e7bdea8265/element/%7Ba2d949ed-768f-479d-92de-ba3ede415785%7D/click timed out after 60 seconds.
 ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
Pages\Screening\TestPage.cs(416,0): at AFTLibrary.Pages.Screening.TestPage.ContinueScreening()
Pages\Screening\ScreeningPage.cs(131,0): at AFTLibrary.Pages.Screening.ScreeningPage.Continue()
Pages\Screening\ScreeningPage.cs(53,0): at AFTLibrary.Pages.Screening.ScreeningPage.ContinueScreening()
ScreeningPageTest.cs(80,0): at ScreeningTests.ScreeningPageTest.CompleteScreeningTest()
--WebException
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 759.38 seconds (NUnit 2.6.1).

My first reaction to this error was 'ohh it cant find the button it is supposed to click' but then that button is loaded on every preceding page and webdriver had no issue finding it. I think it is the webdriver itself that is timing out. I looked up online and found suggestion like using the 'Implicit wait' and the 'set page load timeout' but that didnt really solve my problem. I am using Selenium for Dot NET and this is how I initialize my webdriver

```
    static public IWebDriver GetBrowser()
    {
       IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));
       return driver;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I believe this is a known shortcoming of Selenium's WebDriver. I recommend splitting your tests up into several tests and then running them all in a single suite.

Comment: I am not really sure why are you doing this timeout after initializing the driver. In my case I am using it without any timeout. If you think that 5 minute time is the culprit, how about testing it and checking if division of the tests solves the problem?

Comment: So this doesn't happen when you go DIRECTLY to the section that you want to test and verifying that the clicking doesn't cause a problem?

Comment: @Keikoku Yes that does not happen when I go there directly. It only happens when I test the whole thing at once.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I only tried that because I thought at first the error might have been caused due to a page load timeout because as soon as the button is clicked a new page is supposed to be loaded. It seems to me breaking up the tests is the way to go for this one. I was hoping that there was a better way, other than starting and stopping the screening session.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a large [timeout](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) value for the NUnit test?

Comment: @Faiz I took your suggestion and tried it but it didnt solve my problem the nunit time out only cares about the testcases's instance not the other instances used with in the test  but thank you for taking your time to suggest it.

Comment: @Sophonias - yes I just re read your question and realized my suggestion would not apply.  Unfortunately what you see is a manifestation of a known issue explained in [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/net-bindings-whaddaymean-no-response.html?m=1).